# How to pass argument to the selector which can be used inside that function

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift3, selector, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

here i want to use the class function checkInternet in which i am passing UIViewController so that even if i use this class function in any class then it should change the background color which will show the internet connectivity , So i am getting error as i am not able to pass the argument to another function which can be used inside the function and the background of that UIViewController will be changed.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NetworkConnection.checkInternet(sender:self)
      }


      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }


    }

    -----------------------------------------------------------

        import UIKit
        import Foundation
        import SystemConfiguration

        class NetworkConnection: UIViewController {

          class func checkInternet(sender:UIViewController){
            do {
              reachability = try Reachability()
              NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(_:notification:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
              do {
                try reachability?.startNotifier()
              } catch let error as ReachabilityError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
              } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
              }

            } catch {

            }

          }

          func reachabilityChanged(_ sender:UIViewController ,notification: NSNotification ) {
        guard let reachability = notification.object as? Reachability else { return }
        switch reachability.networkStatus {
        case .notReachable:
          sender.backgroundColor = .red
        case .reachableViaWiFi:
          sender.backgroundColor = .green
        case .reachableViaWWAN:
          sender.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
        print("NetworkStatus: ",reachability.networkStatus)
        print("Reachable: ", reachability.reachable)
        print("Reachable Via WiFi: ", reachability.reachableViaWiFi)
      }
    }
```